# I am getting this error "pdo_mysql extension is not installed"

Tags: magento2, sql, php-pdo

When i use **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy** in ubuntu  i am getting this error **"pdo_mysql extension is not installed"** so please help me?

Comment: Please install/enable pdo_mysql extension.

Answer (score 7):

@SHPatel is right.  There is an answer on askubuntu that gives instructions [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/a/824505/487948)

I am going to assume that you have PHP 7 installed, otherwise you would never have gotten a Magento 2 instance running.  In which case, it is 3 easy steps:

1. If it isn't already, install php7.0-mysql:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
   ```
2. It is possible that it was already installed but the pdo_mysql module wasn't enabled.  Either way, enable pdo_mysql:

   ```
   sudo phpenmod pdo_mysql
   ```
3. Then just restart Apache:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

install PDO extention of SAME php version from EasyApache4 whm