# I am getting error running this command php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Tags: magento2, cron, indexer

I am getting this error while running this command.`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

here is the error

```
  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2.2.5/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:384
    Stack trace:
    #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2.2.5/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<?xml version="...')
    #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2.2.5/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Config/Reader/Dom.php(70): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<?xml version="...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, 'xsi:type', NULL)
    #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2.2.5/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(149): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Reader\Dom->_createConfigMerger('Magento\\Framewo...', '<?xml version="...')
    #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2.2.5/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(130): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->_readFiles(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator))
    #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2.2.5/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(275):  in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2.2.5/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 384
```

Comment: What is the php version you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this issue by running below commands:

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

and

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

***Note: if you are using php 7.1 then type php7.1-xml instead of php-xml***

Comment: Now it's showing  " [Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]           
  pdo_mysql extension is not installed"  this error

Comment: @bhakti, try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188511/i-am-getting-this-error-pdo-mysql-extension-is-not-installed

Comment: @bhakti please follow the blog provided kunj

Comment: @SukumarGorai yes I did, Now I am getting "Failed to restart apache2.service: Unit apache2.service not found."

Comment: I think you have misconfigured Apache. Please restart your system and check if it's properly configured or not